# Webpack-hot-middleware/client module not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

So im getting this error in the terminal `ERROR in multi ./client/src/index.js webpack-hot-middleware/client
Module not found`
I am not sure why because in my project this file is there. I tried the npm install --save command but that didn't change anything. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

1. npm cache clean
2. npm i webpack-hot-middleware --save-dev